# read line and split line of csv file but has comma in a cell

Tags: python, string, csv, split, delimiter

### I have a string line and tried split with the delimiter ','

```
tp = 'A,B,C,"6G,1A",1,2\r\n'
tp.split(',')
```

---

and get the results as with the length of 7

```
['A', 'B', 'C', '"6G', '1A"', '1', '2\r\n']
```

but I want to get the result as to get the length 6

['A', 'B', 'C', '"6G,1A"', '1', '2\r\n']

how can I do that?

Comment: Do any of the answers below help you solve the problem? Is so, please accept one by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you :)

Comment: Where does this line come from, a CSV file?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

```
>>> import csv
>>> tp = 'A,B,C,"6G,1A",1,2\r\n'
>>> rows = list(csv.reader([tp]))
>>> rows
[['A', 'B', 'C', '6G,1A', '1', '2']]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex, in fact, once you know how to use regex.

It is much faster and easier for you to extract text.

```
tp = 'A,B,C,"6G,1A",1,2\r\n'
import re
ab = [s for s in re.split("(,|\\\".*?\\\"|'.*?')", tp)if s.strip(",")]
print(len(ab))
print(ab)

6
['A', 'B', 'C', '"6G,1A"', '1', '2\r\n']
```

Comment: This question is tagged csv, and the sample input conforms to the de facto encoding for CSV, so regex is not a solution; a bona fide CSV parser is the correct approach.

Comment: Perhaps, @ZachYoung, however this will give more opportunities for the user to adapt different situations. 
Like the quote "There's more than one way to cook an egg".
This also portrays how flexible the solution can be.